# Check for surrounding tags

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if a string contains `<br>` tags without any surrounding HTML tags. Is there a regex or any other method to do so?

For example I have strings like this:

```
Lorem ipsum<br><br><br>dolor sit amet
```

or

```
dolor sit amet<br>lorem isum
```

And need them to be

```
<p><br></p><p><br></p>
```

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: cant you just use .includes('<br>')?

Comment: @gogaiosebashvili No, I need the tags to be wrapped between `<p>` tags.

Comment: The question is: why would you ever want to do something like that?! Otherwise this seems much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: What's the expected output for `Lorem ipsum<br><br><br>dolor sit amet`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The text are old strings saved by users which need to be displayed in a new editor which throws error for non-wrapepd <br> tags. So I need to wrap filter these.

Comment: Also obligatory [You can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: @tobifasc Every <br> tag shall be wrapped between <p></p>

Comment: the only safe way I see it's creating a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), setting its `innerHTML` with the raw html and process that node programmatically to find all `<br>` orphans and wrap them as children of a corresponding `<p>`. Any other approach would be looking for troubles.. like the suggested answer below that should be erased for no one to see ever

Comment: So `Lorem ipsum<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>dolor sit amet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a safe method

I investigated how to remove the extra BRs on the fly, but ran out of time

```js
const str = `Lorem ipsum<br><br><br>dolor sit amet

dolor sit amet<br>lorem isum`
const fragment = document.createElement("div");
fragment.innerHTML = str;
fragment.querySelectorAll("br").forEach(br => {
  const wrapper = document.createElement("p");
  br.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, br);
  wrapper.appendChild(br)
})

console.log(fragment.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot to get to a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

so,as far as I see,  you want to wrap your br tags with p tags, you can do that with string.replaceAll function in js, like this:

```
string.replaceAll('<br>','<p> <br> </p>')
```

Comment: The problem is, there also are wrapped tags. So that would double wrap them with `<p>`.

Comment: are  they only wrapped with p tags?

Comment: No, it's quite inconsistent. They are wrapped by several HTML tags, or not wrapped at all. So I'd like to filter the non-wrapped ones.

Comment: @temp Maybe use (.parentNode.nodeName) to see if they're wrapped or not